# Expected value of time-varying signal

Tags: time-series, expected-value

I have a time-varying signal $f(t)$. Couple of probes are trying to measure its values across different time intervals:

\begin{align}
X_1 &= f(t = t_0) + e_1  \\
X_2 &= f(t = t_0+h) + e_2
\end{align}

$e_1$ and $e_2$ are two independent random variables with zero mean and variance = $\sigma^2$. Goal is to estimate the rate of change of the signal using following estimator

$$R = (X_2 - X_1)/h$$

How should I calculate $E(R)$ and $\text{Var}(R)$?

Comment: Just to be clear, the noise variables are independent across time and from each other? And $h$ is a known constant?

Comment: Yes, noise variables are independent of time. h is a "configurable" parameter like the one in kernel density estimator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, you're overthinking this problem. The expectation operator is linear, so we have:
$$
E(R) = \frac{1}{h} \left( E(X_1) - E(X_2) \right)
$$

Then all you have to do is plug in some numbers.

Edit: $f$ is a known function and $t_0$ and $h$ are known values, so $E\left(f(t=t_0)\right)=f(t=t_0)$ and $E\left(f(t=t_0+h)\right)=f(t=t_0+h)$. Then by the same linearity used above, we have
$$
E\left(f(t=t_0) + e_1\right) = E\left(f(t=t_0)\right) + E\left(e_1\right)
$$ and $$
E\left(f(t=t_0 + h) + e_2\right) = E\left(f(t=t_0 + h)\right) + E\left(e_2\right).
$$

Since $E(e_1) = E(e_2) = 0$ by assumption, the expectations are just $f(t=t_0)$ and $f(t=t_0+h)$. Then $E(R) = \frac{1}{h}(f(t=t_0) - f(t=t_0+h))$.

Comment: Thanks @ssdecontrol.

[expectation](http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?%5Cinline%20%5Cdpi%7B120%7D%20E%28e_1%29%20%3D%20E%28e_2%29%20%3D%200%20%5C%5C%20E%28Z%29%20%3D%20h%5E%7B-1%7D%28E%5Bf%28t_0&plus;h%29%5D%20-%20E%5Bf%28t_0%29%5D%5D%29%20%5C%5C%20E%28Z%29%20%3D%20h%5E%7B-1%7DE%28hf%27%28t_0%29%29%20%3D%20f%27%28t_0%29)

Comment: Using Taylor series, this is what I arrived at -

$$
E(e_1) = E(e_2) = 0 \\ E(R) = h^{-1}(E[f(t_0+h)] - E[f(t_0)]]) \\ E(R) = h^{-1}E(hf'(t_0)) = f'(t_0)
$$

Does this sound good to you?

As the $Bias(f'(t),R) = 0$, looks like $R$ is an unbiased estimator for the rate of change.

Comment: @dbose what? you definitely don't need Taylor series for this.

Comment: I added the rest of the soultion into the answer, hopefully it clarifies things